# where can i find information on OpenGL using Linux OS for a total beginner

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I will be using OpenGL for my dissertation and am going through a lot of material to understand it but i am getting confused with the difference in codes and how they use it. Can anyone please send me a link for a beginner to learn OpenGL.

Comment: Are you looking for information on OpenGL ES or OpenGL? Because they're not the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

The website has a good [guide](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_Started) for getting started (see the [Linux](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Platform_specifics%3a_Linux) section).

For OpenGL use the documentation for the API:

http://www.opengl.org/documentation/

Here is OpenGL ES Spec:

http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/

You will need to use a programming language such as C, C++, Python, PERL, Java (Full list here (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL)

You will need a library to handle basic function such as opening windows etc. which most people use GLUT: http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to to download this pdf Mali™ OpenGL ES 2.0 SDK for Linux on
ARM. It would sure help you. (Kindly correct my answer for technical mistakes)